# CSV Format Datasets Appear Disorganized When Opened in Excel

Tags: excel, csv, format, dataset

When I download and open a dataset that's in the `csv` format, it looks messy. I was watching this "*Data Analyst Portfolio Project | SQL Data Exploration | Project 1/4*" video, and I saw that Alex opens the file, and it looks very clean. What is my problem?

Here is the Alex's Excel file when he downloads a dataset in the `csv` format:

[image: Alex's Excel Screenshot]

And here is mine:

[image: My Screenshot]

I tried to solve it with <kbd>Convert text to columns</kbd> button, but it makes the data look more complex than it should. Especially with dates.

Comment: Try searching for the delimiter symbol settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use text to columns. Easy to research, but you click data tab

[image]

Select delineated and comma

[image]

you could also put this in column b and drag down if you have a newer instance of excel

`=TEXTSPLIT(A1,",")`

Comment: I tried that lots of times but it helped me sometimes. I managed to solve the problem with in excel, ->Data->New Query -> From File -> From CSV, dont forget to choose UTF8. By the way, thank you all for the responses.